# How to download files automatically from ftp supported website using Python?

Tags: python, ftp

I want to download some 1500 files which are hosted in a website. The website is username and password protected. I have the username and password. If I download all those individual 1500 files manually then it will be a huge hectic. So i want to download all those files residing in the server automatically through Python.

Is is possible through python ?

Any help in this is appreciated.
Thank a lot.

```
import urllib.request
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(url='http://****/',
                      user='****',
                      passwd='****')
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
urllib.request.urlopen('http://****/')
```

Comment: What you have so far?

Comment: The answer is yes, but to get some help you need to show some research effort or a code snippet.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need python to do it, while `wget` would be enough (with `--input-file=` option if files are hard to wildcard)...

Comment: @m.wasowski : As I am quite comfortable with python, i relied upon it.

Comment: OK, so show us some code you've written so far (generator for URLs would be a nice start).

Comment: @m.wasowski : I added the code which I am trying to implement. But it doesn't work for me. It shows (No module named request)

Comment: @m.wasowski : How to initiate downloading of all those files residing in it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python [`ftplib` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html):

```
>>> from ftplib import FTP
>>> ftp = FTP('ftp.debian.org')     # connect to host, default port
>>> ftp.login()                     # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@
'230 Login successful.'
>>> ftp.cwd('debian')               # change into "debian" directory
>>> ftp.retrlines('LIST')           # list directory contents
-rw-rw-r--    1 1176     1176         1063 Jun 15 10:18 README
...
drwxr-sr-x    5 1176     1176         4096 Dec 19  2000 pool
drwxr-sr-x    4 1176     1176         4096 Nov 17  2008 project
drwxr-xr-x    3 1176     1176         4096 Oct 10  2012 tools
'226 Directory send OK.'
>>> ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> ftp.quit()
```

As you can see you can use `ftp.retrlines` to get information about filenames, and `ftp.retrbinary` to transfer a given file. You can combine these functions to achieve your task.

Comment: In your snippet, where should I add the URL and username, password etc., Also I want to download all the files of type (*.gz) which are present in the website. I want to download all those (*.gz)files and save it in a folder in my system.

Comment: You need to practice finding the appropriate Python documentation, reading through it, and finding the answers you're looking for. The answer to your question is right there in the link I gave you, really easy to find. I've never even used `ftplib`, I just typed "python ftp" into my search engine and the documentation page for `ftplib` was the first thing that came up.